# install vmrc.so plugin for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vmware, plugins

I want to install **VMWare-VMRC plugin** for chrome,

I downloaded VMware-VMRC.x86_64.bundle, and follow the installer,
built the **/opt/google/chrome/plugins** directory and a **np-vmware-vmrc-5.5.0-1280474.so** file in it.

The installer works well for firefox, but not for chrome.

**chrome://plugin** still doesn’t show the vmrc plugin and the site still asking me to install the plugin.
Please help.

Comment: please refer [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vmrc.pg.doc%2Fvmrc_pg_overview.3.3.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doesn't work for chrome.  That plugin uses an outdated method that is no longer supported.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/RtsoU4ee1YI/Atie1UZgFQwJ

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.